# VSTS test agent is not running test build as X64 bit process, "no matching test is present" error is being displayed

Tags: azure, testing, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

We are running these test as part of VSTS pipline on Azure VM, test agent get deployed successfuly but run function test task fails. we are building whole solution containing test solution as x64 bit

Answer (score 0):

Refer to these steps and check the result:

1. Create a runsettings file (xml file) to specify TargetPlatform

Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<RunSettings> 
  <RunConfiguration>
    <ResultsDirectory>.\TestResults</ResultsDirectory>
    <TargetPlatform>x64</TargetPlatform>
  </RunConfiguration>
 </RunSettings>
```

2. Add it to source control
3. Specify that file for Run Functional Tests step.

[image]

Update:

These are my build steps:

1. Visual Studio Build

[image]

2. Windows Machine File Copy

[image]

3. Visual Studio Test Agent Deployment
4. Run Functional Tests

[image]

Comment: I tried this but it did not work, only difference was I was running it thru test plan not test assembly

Comment: @Ankit It is working for me. What're detail steps (include settings) of your build definition? Make sure the necessary assembly file is in Test Drop Location and Test plan, Test Suite and Test Configuration are correct.

Comment: @Ankit I added my build steps to my answer, you can check it.